# Woocommerce admin order page details - Email is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

[image]
This is my form when admin submit it mail has too be shoot 
but when i click on submit getting order updated but i am not reciving mail

my code is this as i m not pro in developing its might be mistake please review and solve this i want to echo all field on woocomerce admin detailpage only and also submit on that page

```
function html_form_code() {
    echo '<form action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '" method="post">';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Your Name (required) <br/>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="cf-name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-name"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-name"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Your Email (required) <br/>';
    echo '<input type="email" name="cf-email" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-email"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-email"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Subject (required) <br/>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="cf-subject" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-subject"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-subject"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Your Message (required) <br/>';
    echo '<textarea rows="10" cols="35" name="cf-message">' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-message"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-message"] ) : '' ) . '</textarea>';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p><input type="submit" name="cf-submitted" value="Send"></p>';
    echo '</form>';
}

function deliver_mail() {

    // if the submit button is clicked, send the email
    if ( isset( $_POST['cf-submitted'] ) ) {

        // sanitize form values
        $name    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-name"] );
        $email   = sanitize_email( $_POST["cf-email"] );
        $subject = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-subject"] );
        $message = esc_textarea( $_POST["cf-message"] );

        // get the blog administrator's email address
        $to = get_option( 'admin_email' );

        $headers = "From: $name <$email>" . "\r\n";

        // If email has been process for sending, display a success message
        if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {
            echo '<div>';
            echo '<p>Thanks for contacting me, expect a response soon.</p>';
            echo '</div>';
        } else {
            echo 'An unexpected error occurred';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'dbx_post_sidebar', 'html_form_code', 10, 1);
```

Comment: Did you check your spam ? I suppose wp_mail is functionnal, so there are two options :
1: Your data aren't set(do a var_dump on your variables to check that values are set)
2: If you're testing from a localhost website, there is a high chance that your mail is treated like a spam (send it from an SSL encrypted website to avoid this problem).

Comment: ya i checked but didnt got any mail

Answer (score 0):

Please add below line in your code and let me know what happen.

```
add_action('init','deliver_mail');
```

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: remove the form action as well and than try i checked in my system it is working

Comment: I guess you are new in the wordpress any of the function is not called automatically it is always required to called them.

Comment: I sir please can u help me with my second question please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50591859/woocommerce-admin-order-detail-page-shipping

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692759/woo-commerce-registration-form-add-otp-as-custom-field

Comment: please help sir